# MySQL error MySQL # 1415 on Trigger creation

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger using PHPMyadmin GUI, but encountered an error MySQL # 1415. Here is my query for the trigger.

```
SELECT *
FROM `manage_order` O
INNER JOIN `manage_transaction` T ON T.txn_id = O.trans_id
WHERE O.`trans_status` = 'Completed' && O.`order_via` = 'Bid' && O.`release_flag` = 'Y'
ORDER BY O.`added_date` DESC;

INSERT INTO `manage_site_income_details`
VALUES (NULL, T.t_id, T.about, O.order_id, O.order_amt * 0.035, NOW());
```

Comment: You cannot return a result set in a trigger (ie your select) please publish your trigger and explain your intent.

Comment: As you can see, I want to insert row into table `manage_site_income_details` based on condition if the table 'manage_order' is updated. However, I have ensure that transaction table  'manage_transaction' has also updated. There I need some inputs from both tables for inserting a row into the table `manage_site_income_details. So, please guide me how to make a conditional trigger.`

Comment: There is no such thing as a conditional trigger - a trigger will fire when an action occurs (insert/update/delete) - you can have conditions within the trigger. But from your  last comment a trigger may not be appropriate consider a procedure instead.

Comment: Can we call a procedure on an event such as insert and update?

Comment: No you can't but you can have many sql statements in a procedure..